# DynamoDB with daily/weekly/monthly aggregated values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My application is creating a log file every 10min, which I want to store in DynamoDB in an aggregated way, e.g. 144 log files per day, 1008 log files per week or ~4400 log files per month.
I have different partition keys, but for sake of simplicity I have used only a single partition key in the following examples.

The straight forward solution would be to have different tables, e.g.

**Table "TenMinLogsDay":**

```
id (=part.key) | date (=sort key) | cntTenMinLogs | data
-------------- | ---------------- | ------------- | -------------------------------
 1             | 2017-04-30       | 144           | some serialized aggregated data
 1             | 2017-05-01       | 144           | some serialized aggregated data
 1             | 2017-05-02       | 144           | some serialized aggregated data
 1             | 2017-05-03       | 144           | some serialized aggregated data
```

**Table "TenMinLogsWeek":**

```
id (=part.key) | date (=sort key) | cntTenMinLogs | data
-------------- | ---------------- | ------------- | -------------------------------
 1             | 2017-05-01       | 1008          | some serialized aggregated data
 1             | 2017-05-08       | 1008          | some serialized aggregated data
 1             | 2017-05-15       | 1008          | some serialized aggregated data
```

**Table "TenMinLogsMonth":**

```
id (=part.key) | date (=sort key) | cntTenMinLogs | data
-------------- | ---------------- | ------------- | -------------------------------
 1             | 2017-05-01       | 4464          | some serialized aggregated data
 1             | 2017-06-01       | 4320          | some serialized aggregated data
 1             | 2017-07-01       | 4464          | some serialized aggregated data
```

I would prefer however a combined table. Out of the box DynamoDB does not seem to support this.
Also, I want to query either the daily OR the weekly OR the monthly aggregated items, thus I don't want to use the filter feature for this.

The following solution would be possible, but seems like a poor hack:

**Table "TenMinLogsCombined":**

```
id (=part.key) | date (=sort key) | week (=LSI sort key) | month (=LSI sort key) | cntTenMinLogs | data
-------------- | ---------------- | -------------------- | --------------------- | ------------- | -----
 1             | 2017-04-30       |   (empty)            |   (empty)             | 144           | ...
 1             | 2017-05-01       |   (empty)            |   (empty)             | 144           | ...
 1             | 0017-05-01       | 2017-05-01           |   (empty)             | 1008          | ...
 1             | 1017-05-01       |   (empty)            | 2017-05-01            | 4464          | ...
 1             | 2017-05-02       |   (empty)            |   (empty)             | 144           | ...
 1             | 2017-05-03       |   (empty)            |   (empty)             | 144           | ...
```

Explanation:
By using the year "0017" and "1017" instead of "2017" I can query the date range for, e.g. 2017-05-01 to 2017-05-04 and DynamoDB won't read the items starting with 0017 or 1017
For week or month range queries, such a hack is not required, as empty LSI sort keys are possible.

Does anybody know of a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on requirements here. It seems like you're trying to achieve things like aggregation and grouping which are fairly straightforward in a relational database where DynamoDB is better suited for unstructured data. I'd almost consider throwing the logs in S3 then using Athena ( https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/ ) to do queries on the data. Even if you solve this issue, I feel like you're just going to hit more road bumps later.

Comment: +1 on previous comment. Also consider solutions like Redshift/Redshift Spectrum or ELK stack (Logstash/Elasticsearch/Kibana)

Comment: You are correct: The DynamoDB is not best for time based data. We have switched to the time series database "InfluxDB" which supports these things out of the box. AWS Athena is unfortunately not working, as it supports only a handful of data formats (e.g. CSV). Custom data (in my case protobuf serialized source files) are not supported by Athena.